# moment.tz is giving incorrect result

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I was trying to convert dates according to selected timezone. I was surprised to see same result for dates with 5 mins of time difference.
For ex,

```
var x = "2017-07-10T18:30:00.000Z"
var y = "2017-07-10T18:35:00.000Z"
var z = "2017-07-10T18:45:00.000Z"
```

and tried converting them to using moment.tz:

```
moment.tz(x, 'America/New_York').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS');
moment.tz(y, 'America/New_York').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS')
moment.tz(z, 'America/New_York').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS')
```

To my surprise, result was same for all 3 being `"10/07/2017 14:07:00"`.
What's going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The issue is that you are using uppercase `MM` (month) instead of lowercase `mm` minutes in you [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Note that, you have the same problem for `SS` (fractional seconds) and `ss` (seconds).

---

**General note about you code sample:**

Use [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) for parsing time string using a given timezone (e.g. `'America/New_York'`), [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) is not made for converting input to given timezone.

You have to use [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) method to convert a moment object to a given timezone.

Note that your input string ends with `Z` so it represents time in UTC.

---

As Matt Johnson pointed out in comments, in your case even `moment.tz(input, zone)` would convert input to given zone because input string contains the `Z` (that stays for UTC timezone). Anyway this kind of approach is discouraged.

---

Here a code sample that [parses UTC](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) time string and converts it to `'America/New_York'` timezone:

```js
var x = "2017-07-10T18:30:00.000Z";
var y = "2017-07-10T18:35:00.000Z";
var z = "2017-07-10T18:45:00.000Z";

console.log( moment.utc(x).tz('America/New_York').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS') );
console.log( moment.utc(y).tz( 'America/New_York').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss') );
console.log( moment.utc(z).tz( 'America/New_York').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can we get back to x from output of console.log? Is there a reverse mechanism?

Comment: Actually, because the input contains the `Z`, it will indeed be treated as UTC and converted with just `moment.tz(input, zone)`.  It's slightly bad form though, as just dropping the Z will change the behavior, so I'd still go with your approach instead. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson thank you for your comment, I've edited my answer in order to include that info to it. Thank you for sharing this momentjs behaviour (that I think is completely reasonable, but a bit surprising and not so well documented). I'm learning a lot from this kind of contributions :)

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh what do you mean with _ get back to x from output of console.log_? I suggest to explain it better, probably the best thing to do is to post another question with this new requirement.