# How to convert date and time to different timezones in momentjs

Tags: angular, momentjs

In my angular app I have a selectbox, where the user can select to which timezone he/she wants to convert a specific time. Currently I'm using momentjs for date-time manipulations, the problem is I don't know, how to change the date-times's timezone dynamically, as momentjs has only `.utc()` method.

Till now I used only one timezone, so I've hard-coded the `utc()` method.

My service:

```
public convertDate(): void {
    this.date = moment(this.date).utc().format("DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm");
}
```

Should be (pseudo code):

```
public convertDate(selectedTimezone: string): void {
    this.date = moment(this.date).selectedTimezone().format("DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm");
}
```

Comment: You can to use [`tz(String)`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) of [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.tz is giving incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009474/moment-tz-is-giving-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

1. Install the moment-timezone:
   `npm install --save moment-timezone`
2. Install types: `npm install -D @types/moment-tipes`
3. Import to your service: `import "moment-tipes"`

In your angular service:

```
public convertDate(selectedTimezone: string): void {
    this.date = moment(this.date).tz(selectedTimezone).format("DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm");
}
```

Comment: It's: npm install -D @types/moment-timezone