# What are the differences between the way we construct moment timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z").tz("America/Los_Angeles")` vs `moment.tz("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z", "America/Los_Angeles")`

According to https://momentjs.com/timezone/ the example show both but it didnt explain which way is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that moment-timezone examples are a bit misleading, please note that [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) is for **parsing** input using given zone:

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

while [`tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) is to **convert** a moment object to a given timezone.

---

For `"2014-06-01T12:00:00Z"` both `moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z").tz("America/Los_Angeles")` and `moment.tz("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z", "America/Los_Angeles")` give the same result because the input contains the `Z` that stands for `+00:00` offset.

Note that as stated by Matt Johnson (momentjs team member and date/timezone guru) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009474/moment-tz-is-giving-incorrect-result#comment77007724_45009828):

> because the input contains the `Z`, it will indeed be treated as UTC and converted with just `moment.tz(input, zone)`. It's slightly bad form though, as just dropping the Z will change the behavior

So my suggestions is to use [`moment.utc`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse UTC inputs and then convert to desired timezone using [`tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/). See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45009474/4131048).

---

Here a couple of examples of using different approaches for parsing different inputs:

```js
// UTC input
console.log( moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z").tz("America/Los_Angeles").format() );
console.log( moment.tz("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z", "America/Los_Angeles").format() );
// No Z in the input (no UTC)
console.log( moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00").tz("America/Los_Angeles").format() );
console.log( moment.tz("2014-06-01T12:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles").format() );

// My suggested way
console.log( moment.utc("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z").tz("America/Los_Angeles").format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```