# Moment & Timezone convert local time fails

Tags: node.js, typescript, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

This is in an Ionic based hybrid app on NodeJS.

Trying to convert a local time as specified by a user input to another timezone, yet it fails:

```
static MTL_local_time_to_server(aDateTime:moment.Moment):moment.Moment{
    console.log(aDateTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));

    const localTime:moment.Moment = momenttz.tz(aDateTime, momenttz.tz.guess());
    console.log(localTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'), momenttz.tz.guess());
    const returnTime:moment.Moment = momenttz(localTime).tz("Europe/Berlin");
    console.log(returnTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
    return returnTime;
}
```

Prints

```
April 22nd 2019, 12:00:00 am 
April 22nd 2019, 12:00:00 am America/Los_Angeles 
April 22nd 2019, 9:00:00 am
```

Comment: Probably related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45009474/4131048), if `localDateTime` ends with `Z` _will indeed be treated as UTC and converted with just `moment.tz(input, zone)`_. See linked accepted answer and its comments for further info.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks for your suggestion, but removing the `Z` still fails, see above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- You've typed the output of `moment.tz` as a `string`, but it's actually a `Moment` object.
- When you call `JSON.stringify` on a `Moment` object, it returns the output of `.toISOString()`, which is always in UTC.  (The `Z` indicates UTC in the ISO 8601 format.)
- It's not clear if your input is a `string` or a `Date` object.  If it's a `string`, then the `Z` indicates UTC, so it will always be interpreted as UTC.  If it's a `Date` object, then the point in time represented by that `Date` object will be used - which depends on how you constructed the `Date` object.  Either way, the value you're showing is UTC based, not local time.
- It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  From your variable names, it would seem like you are trying to convert `localDateTime` to `localTime`, which logically would give the same value if they were both "local".

  - If you're trying to convert a value from local time to Berlin time, then:

    ```
    moment(yourInput).tz('Europe/Berlin')
    ```
  - If you're trying to convert a value from Los Angeles time to Berlin time, then:

    ```
    moment.tz(yourInput, 'America/Los_Angeles').tz('Europe/Berlin')
    ```
  - If you're trying to convert a value from UTC to local time, you don't need moment-timezone at all:

    ```
    moment.utc(yourInput).local()
    ```
- If you need string outputs, then you should call the `format` function to produce a string.  What you showed here looks like you are logging `Moment` objects not strings.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll check that out. In my IDE `moment.tz` seems to return `any`, not a specific type. Hence I was lost. I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, but I was only importing the `moment-timezone`, not `moment` for the types.

Comment: You might also want to consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead of Moment.  It has time zone support included, and is designed for modern development workflow.

Comment: I edited my question based to make it clearer. Essentially doing the double conversion that you list.

Comment: I see the edit, but it's still unclear what you are *trying* to accomplish.  You say "local time as specified by a user input" but you're providing a moment object as input.  How did you construct that object?  A [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example would be very useful in helping you.

Comment: Also, what's with all the tz guessing?  It seems you're running this on the server in node.js? If so, you shouldn't be working with "local time" at all.  The server's time zone isn't local to anyone.

Comment: Running as ionic based hybrid app in nodejs. User input time zone depends on the users location. This code is on a phone. Added to edit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that helps somewhat.  It's still unclear what you want `momenttz.tz(aDateTime, momenttz.tz.guess())` to do.  If you built `aDateTime` via something like `moment(userInput)`, then it's *already* in local time.    Also, what is wrong with the output?  Midnight on April 2nd in Los Angeles is indeed 9am in Berlin.  (On that date, Berlin is UTC+2 and LA is UTC-7, so that's the 9 hour difference.)

Comment: You're right. 12AM is midnight. Damn AM/PM notation ( European speaking here :D ). Thanks for you help. I think I now found the solution.